# Color a list of 2D points continuously

Tags: list-manipulation, color, visualization

I have a list of 3-tuples. First 2 positions are coordinates in $R^2$, the third specifies concentration of a chemical at that point, which I want to render in color.  Here's what the list looks like:

```
list={{0.1, 0.1, 0.000100686}, {0.1, 0.2, 0.000139706}, {0.1, 0.3,0.000158851}... {0.2, 0.1, 0.000149521}...{4,4,0.00151234}}
```

I've tried

```
 BubbleChart[list, ColorFunction -> (Hue[#3] &)]
```

Which doesn't look all that bad, but I was thinking of something more smooth that blends over values continuously.

For example, Mathematica interpolates (I guess) over a list of points for ListPlot3D to give you a (hopefully) smooth surface, as opposed to ListPointPlot3D where the points are explicitly shown, I'm looking for the equivalent of that in color.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The example list is not very well suited to coloring, unless some rescaling is done, or you have a color function specially suited to your concentrations. In any case: would you want the points to be joined by lines, or do you need them to remain as points?

Comment: @J.M. I'd rather have them remain as points. But I'm hoping to find a way to have the entire 2D domain colored, where mathematica will color each pixel given the value of the concentration in the closest node. Just like ListPlot3D gives you a surface even though you have only input discrete points.

And you mean these values are too little for any kind of range of colors to describe them? I think I could work my way around that when I get realistic values, these are just test runs.

Comment: Do all points have identical x-values? If not, post more points, if so, why not do this in 2d?

Comment: @Feyre Nah, my numbering just goes from bottom to top and then shifts to the next x value. I'll adjust the list to make more sense.

Comment: Does `Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[Drop[list, None, -1], VertexColors -> (ColorData["ThermometerColors", #] & /@ Rescale[list[[All, -1]]])]}]` look like something you want?

Comment: @Craig It sounds like you can just feed your data to `ListDensityPlot` to color the whole domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like the following:

```
    ListDensityPlot[list, PlotLegends->True, ColorFunction->"Rainbow"]
```